# Who are Jeigh, Orro and Vammar?

Tags: dark-souls-2

When you enter into the memories to get the Giant Souls and the Giant's Kinship, the area names are

> *Memory of (Orro/Jeigh/Vammar)*

Who are these characters? I'm assuming it's the sleeping Giants? I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are the sleeping giants.

http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Memory+of+Orro
http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Memory+of+jeigh
http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Memory+of+vammar

You reach a certain point into the game that you have to enter the memories of those sleeping giants to retrieve their souls if i'm not mistaken.

Acording to the game's lore, the Vendrick fought against them, but i'm not really sure of this..it's been a while since i've played the game.

You have to get an item in ordem to enter the memories.

Comment: Could you summarise some of the main points that are relevant to the question, to avoid link rot.